# Any method to solve auto-suggestive dropdown method using keys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

lang:java

**I have been trying to automate auto suggestive dropdowns, but if I give the both the text and keys in single line, it is not giving the site to load options. Keeping this thing in mind, I went ahead with thread sleep method and waited for the suggestions to load, but the cursor is coming out of the web element and keys operations are not being performed. please help me with this....**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class suggestivedropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\teddy\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    //  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromCity']")).clear(); this is if it contains default option
      WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromCity']"));
      source.sendKeys("HYD");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    source.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    source.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      WebElement destination=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='toCity']"));
       destination.sendKeys("MUM");
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       destination.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
       destination.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use hard coded sleeps in the code . If you are facing synchronization issue use waits to avoid issues, Refer below solution :

```
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromCity']"))).sendKeys("Hyd");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Hyderabad, India')]"))).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='toCity']"))).sendKeys("Mumbai");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Mumbai, India')]"))).click();
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but isn't there no way to select options from dropdown using keys 
 methods?

Comment: its a custom drop down so you can't directly handle it

Comment: Can you please tell me how will you approach Paytm flight dropdowns?

Comment: Where it is in the application?

Comment: Paytm.com/flights

Comment: I have used parent child traverse to get the element as the html layout is different but if you can find any other way, please share.

Comment: DOm is not same as your previsous app. you can use css locator :::  from .col-xs-2:nth-child(2) #text-box
to  
.col-xs-2:nth-child(4) #text-box